# Extract data from object using a path - include all data in arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash, flatmap

*I am trying to solve the following problem with LoDash.  I know how to solve the problem using for loops, but am looking for the modern functional method of solving the problem.*

---

I have the following data:

```
const data = {
    people: [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            vehicles: [
                {
                    model: "Mazda"
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 },
                        { pressure: 22 },
                        { pressure: 23 },
                        { pressure: 21 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    model: "Harley Davidson"
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 }
                        { pressure: 25 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

From it, I want to extract a list of every tire pressure belonging to every person.  So something like this:

```
[20, 22, 23, 21, 20, 25, ... ]
```

What I am looking for is a method that I can call like this:

```
const path = 'people.vehicles[*].tires[*].pressure';
const tirePressure = _.methodName(data, path);
```

I know that lodash has support for some similar functionality - like `_.at(object, ['a[0].b.c', 'a[1]']);` [(link)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#at), but it doesn't support collapsing the entire array, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using a [Lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) [`flatMap`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap). This could probably get shorter using [`flatMapDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMapDeep) but this way it's much clearer IMHO.

```js
const data = {
    people: [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            vehicles: [
                {
                    model: "Mazda",
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 },
                        { pressure: 22 },
                        { pressure: 23 },
                        { pressure: 21 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    model: "Harley Davidson",
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 },
                        { pressure: 25 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};


const pressures = _(data.people)
  .flatMap(_.property('vehicles'))
  .flatMap(_.property('tires'))
  .map(_.property('pressure'))
  .value();

console.log(pressures);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a classical iterative and recursive approach and return only the found values of `pressure`.

```js
function getPressures(o) {
    return [].concat(...Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) =>
        key === 'pressure'
            ? value
            : value && typeof value === 'object'
                ? getPressures(value)
                : []
    ));
}

var data = { people: [{ name: "Bob", vehicles: [{ model: "Mazda", tires: [{ pressure: 20 }, { pressure: 22 }, { pressure: 23 }, { pressure: 21 }] }, { model: "Harley Davidson", tires: [{ pressure: 20 }, { pressure: 25 }] }] }] };

console.log(getPressures(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A different approach is to implement an get method for a path with works with wildcards as well the result is an object with the pathes as keys and the wanted values.

```js
function get(object, path) {

    function iter(o, p, i) {
        if (i === parts.length) {
            result[p.join('.')] = o;
            return;
        }
        if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') {
            return;
        }
        if (parts[i] === '*') {
            Object
                .entries(o)
                .forEach(([k, v]) => iter(v, p.concat(k), i + 1));
            return;
        }
        if (parts[i] in o) {
            iter(o[parts[i]], p.concat(parts[i]), i + 1);
        }
    }

    var result = {},
        parts = path.split('.');

    iter(object, [], 0);
    return result;
}

var data = { people: [{ name: "Bob", vehicles: [{ model: "Mazda", tires: [{ pressure: 20 }, { pressure: 22 }, { pressure: 23 }, { pressure: 21 }] }, { model: "Harley Davidson", tires: [{ pressure: 20 }, { pressure: 25 }] }] }] },
    result = get(data, 'people.*.vehicles.*.tires.*.pressure'),
    values = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have done with simple `JS` like

Use `.map` to get the tire values and then flatten this array

```js
const data = {
    people: [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            vehicles: [
                {
                    model: "Mazda",
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 },
                        { pressure: 22 },
                        { pressure: 23 },
                        { pressure: 21 },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    model: "Harley Davidson",
                    tires: [
                        { pressure: 20 },
                        { pressure: 25 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
var x=  data.people[0].vehicles.map(o=> o.tires.map(i=> i.pressure))

console.log(x.join(",").split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract a list of every tire pressure belonging to every person, you can use `reduce` and group all the tire pressure values to respective name, and use object data structure to store the output:

```
const data={people:[{name:"Bob",vehicles:[{model:"Mazda",tires:[{pressure:20},{pressure:22},{pressure:23},{pressure:21}]},{model:"Harley Davidson",tires:[{pressure:20},{pressure:25}]}]}]};

const result = data.people.reduce((all, {name, vehicles}) => {

  const pressures  = vehicles.reduce((total, {tires}) => {
    tires.forEach(({pressure}) => total.push(pressure));
    return total;
  }, []);

  all[name] = pressures;

  return all;

}, {});

console.log(result);
```